# Using JSoup to extract a string from within a string

Tags: java, html, string, jsoup

I am currently having trouble extracting a string from a string. In the following example:

```
<a class="gb1" href="http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&amp;tab=wi">Images</a>
```

I want to extract "http" through "&amp" but only know how to extract one. The string changes every time so I can't write that part out exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: When you say it changes everytime, does it become an arbitrary string or is it always formatted the same but with different content for the href portion?

Comment: Basically always the same. If I can get it working so that it is always the same, that'll be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using a full blown library when you are able to extract via `String#substring()`? Search for the start of the `href` value of the link and stop at the next `"` to get the `href` content or stop after the first `&amp;` you encounter after the `href` part.